# Call WebService With Xamarin Forms (Using Vs 2019)

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin

Trying to Call WebService With Xamarin Forms

getting this error after run it 
`System.InvalidOperationException: 'A Binding must be configured for this channel factory`

This is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace And.Saby8
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            login_ico.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("And.Saby8.image.logo.png");
            btn_login.Clicked += Btn_login_Clicked;

        }

        public async void Btn_login_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              myapp.myappSoapClient ws = new myapp.myappSoapClient();

            login resulto = await ws.loginsAsync(username.Text, password.Text);

            if (resulto.validuser)
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
            else
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {

                    DisplayAlert("Eror", "", "OK");

                });

        }


}
}
```

is there somthing wrong, is there alternative of Completed Event (loginsCompleted witch not available in vs2019)

Can you help me please ?

Thanks.

Comment: do yourself a huge favor and do NOT use SOAP.  It is a miserable experience.  However, if you must, there are multiple existing questions that address the specific error message you're getting.  Have you read any of them?

Comment: thank you mr @Jason for the answer, what s the alternative of SOAP .

Comment: REST - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest